# How to find OS X, iMac, MacBook exact CPU version?

Tags: macos, mac

When clicking Apple Logo -> About my Mac, I see only some basic informations about the processor.

Processor: 3.06 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo

How it's possible to check the exact version of Mac OS X processor model?

Comment: Take a look: http://www.tekrevue.com/tip/find-mac-cpu-model/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open your terminal and type

```
sysctl -n machdep.cpu.brand_string
```